# Retrieve 16:9 youtube thumbnails instead of the 4:3 black bordered ones?

Tags: php, youtube

I'm trying to use PHP to retrieve a list of recent uploaded videos from a Youtube channel however the thumbnails are all in 4:3 format with black borders at the top and bottom.
I am using the following to retrieve the thumbnails:

```
$thumbnail = (string)$media->group->thumbnail[0]->attributes()->url;
```

and this to import them:

```
<img src="<?php echo $thumbnail;?>"/>
```

The youtube API website and various other Q&A websites say you can use the variable

```
yt:name='mqdefault'
```

to retrieve the 16:9 thumbnails with no borders, however I have no clue where to incorporate this into the PHP?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/mqdefault.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/maxresdefault.jpg
```

You would need you url to look similar to one of those. 
Not sure what:
`(string)$media->group->thumbnail[0]->attributes()->url;` is returning but I would take a look at that URL and make sure it resembles something similar to above.

For you below example you want you URL to resemble this.

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/0GQPoyMr30o/mqdefault.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/0GQPoyMr30o/maxresdefault.jpg
```

Try doing something like this:

```
<?php 
$thumbnail = (string)$media->group->thumbnail[0]->attributes()->url;
$thumbnail = str_replace('0.jpg', 'mqdefault.jpg', $thumbnail);
?>

<img src="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>" />
```

Comment: The URL is being returned as: http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/0GQPoyMr30o/0.jpg so i'm not sure how I would go about removing the 0.jpg and changing it to mqdefualt, any ideas?

Comment: Do you have access to the youtube video ID's in your media variable?

Comment: Thanks  a lot using the $thumbnail = str_replace('0.jpg', 'mqdefault.jpg', $thumbnail); worked perfectly

Comment: Not a problem. I am not 100% sure that they are all 0.jpg by default. I would look into printing out your $media variable and see if you have an ID to work with. Then just use the URL above and replace <insert-youtube-video-id-here> with your ID .